# как изменить тип Series?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

Делаю программу в Windows forms на c++. Использую элемент Chart. Пытаюсь изменить тип одного из компонентов на другой. Например с Column (столбцы) на Line (ломанная линия). Не могу понять что надо сделать. После ChartType среди свойств не нахожу типы.

```
 System::Void info1::MyForm::MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    this->chart1->Series[0]->ChartType->Line;
}
```

Comment: `->ChartType = SeriesChartType::Line;`

Comment: @alexander выдаёт три ошибки: 
Ошибка C2065 Line: необъявленный идентификатор
Ошибка C2653 SeriesChartType: не является именем класса или пространства 
Ошибка (активно) E0276 имя, за которым следует выражение "::", должно определять класс или пространство имен